# throwing exception inside the catch block

Tags: java, mysql, exception

```
    public void onClick() throws SQLException   
  try {
 // Do something
} catch(MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException e) { 
     //Can i convert this exception to SQL Exception
}
```

Can i convert MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException to SQLException which is thrown by the method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can wrap and rethrow - if you think it adds more information or makes your ideas more general.  I think in this case the exception you're catching gives more info than the one you're thinking about.

I wouldn't choose a SQLException, though.  It's a checked exception.  I think the tide has turned from checked to unchecked exceptions.

Spring wraps SQLExceptions into unchecked DataAccessException that extends RuntimeException.  I'd suggest that you follow suit.

Here's how you should do it:

```
catch(MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException e) { 
    throw new SQLException(e);
}
```

Don't just pass the message.  Give the whole stack trace.

Comment: You're absolutely correct ("Don't just pass the message..."), but see my updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

But the MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException already **is** a SQLExecption (through inheritence)! So there's no need to rethrow it (just remove the try/catch-block).

Comment: Excellent point.  The only reason to wrap it that I can see would be to hide the fact that it's MySQL underneath or to use a custom exception hierarchy.  But even then I'd say it's not important.  How often to people change databases?  It's more likely that you'll rewrite the middle tier.  I upvoted your answer now.

Comment: @duffymo - Yes, absolutely, another reason not to just pass the SQLException along would be if there were more catch-clauses and other exceptions handled -- but that's not present in OPs question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the construtor of `SQLException` to create one in your `Catch` Block..

```
try {
} catch (MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException e) {
    throw new SQLException(e);
}
```

Comment: I think this is not the way to go.  Pass the original exception.

Comment: @duffymo. That can also be done.. But this is also not wrong either.. Still I'll edit it..

Comment: I didn't say it can't be done.  I said it's not the way to go.  See my code above.  It gives more info back to the handler class - the stack trace.

Comment: @duffymo.. Yeah in that you are right.. That's why I updated my answer.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since `MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` is subclass of `SQLException` re throwing is unnecessary. If you want to abstract your business logic layer from database specific details, make sure to catch SQL Exceptions in the logic layer so that even if the database is switched logic would still valid.